# Can we force the SharePoint Lookup field to be delegable inside Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

We have a list named Large123, and inside another list we define a lookup field named ll to reference the Large123 list, as follow:-

[image]

but when we try to do a Lookup formula on the Lookup SharePoint field inside our Power Apps, we always get Delegation warning, as follow:-

[image]

but if we change the formula to be as follow, the delegation warning will get disappeared:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this ? why one formula raised a delegation warning while the other did not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try for your `ll.Id=Value(9)` this shall most probably work.

[image]

[Ref Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview#filter-functions)